# Why two different ProductCode (aka Product Code) fields in InstallShield?

Tags: installshield

In InstallShield, why are there two productcode settings? One is in general information and another in releases > productconfig. The latter seems to be the one that matters for major upgrades. Likewise there are duplicate Upgrade Code and Package Code fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product Configurations are a way of building variations of an installer from a single source project.  Through the use of release flags you can create different MSI's with different feature sets and then you can override the ProductName, ProductVersion, ProductCode and UpgradeCode  to give the resultant MSIs different meta context.

An example would be a Lite, Standard and Professional version of your product.